# IPv4Network in Python - Calculating next minimum subnet of different size?

Tags: python-3.x, networking, ip, ip-address, subnet

I'm working with the `ipaddress` module in Python and trying to figure out a way of calculating the next available subnet (of either the same prefix or a different prefix) that doesn't overlap the existing subnet (the new subnet **MUST** be greater than the old one).

Lets say I start with network:

```py
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

# From 10.90.1.0 to 10.90.1.31
main_net = IPv4Network("10.90.1.0/27")
```

I know the next available address is going to be `10.90.1.32`, I can even figure this out quite easily by doing:

```py
next_ip = main_net.broadcast_address + 1
# will output 10.90.1.32
print(next_ip)
```

If I wanted to find the next `/27`, I just create a new network like so:

```py
# From 10.90.1.32 to 10.90.1.63
new_net = IPv4Network(f"{next_ip}/27")
```

This is all very straightforward so far, but now what if the next subnet I am looking for is a `/26` or a `/28` - how can I find the next minimum start IP address for either of these cases in Python?

I have explored using the `supernet` method, for example I could do something like this:

```py
# Will print 10.90.1.0/26
print(main_net.supernet(new_prefix=27))
```

The problem with this method is that it will print `10.90.1.0/26` which overlaps the existing `10.90.1.0/27` network, I could make a loop and get it to keep generated the next `/26` until they stop overlapping, but it seems inefficient to me.  Surely, there is a better way?

Comment: There are a couple of sections in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that explain how to do this, but not with specific code. Remember that IPv4 addresses are simply 32-bit unsigned integers.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful, kinda what I was looking for.  Just need to spend some time reading through it and making sense of it.  Have already worked on the binary level but was certain there was an existing proven method of doing this so didn't want to reinvent te wheel.  Will also wait to see if someone hs already done this in Python as I'm sure someone must of!

Comment: I actually created my own IP objects (one for IPv4 and one for IPv6) that do and provide exactly what I need, but that is not in Python. All the objects store are the IP address and mask (32 bits each for IPv4 and 128 bits each for IPv6), and everything else is properties or methods and the values are created on the fly as needed.

Comment: Yep think I am going to need to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ron, I think I figured it out now.  Have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Ron Maupin's helpful comment leading to a useful guide, I have managed to make a function that does this.  I still want to test it a bit more but believe it is correct:

```py
def calculate_next_ip_network(ip_bytes, current_prefix, next_prefix):
    next_prefix_mask = (~((1 << (32 - next_prefix)) - 1)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    if next_prefix <= current_prefix:
        bit_shift = 32 - next_prefix
    else:
        bit_shift = 32 - current_prefix
    new_ip = (((next_prefix_mask & ip_bytes) >> bit_shift) + 1) << bit_shift
    return bytes([new_ip >> i & 0xFF for i in (24, 16, 8, 0)])
```

Usage:

```py
nt = IPv4Network("10.90.1.56/29")
current_prefix = nt.prefixlen
next_prefix = 25
ip_bytes = int.from_bytes(nt.network_address.packed, byteorder="big")
next_ip = calculate_next_ip_network(ip_bytes, current_prefix, next_prefix)
print(IPv4Address(next_ip))
# Should print "10.90.1.128"
```